# Intersecting Floating Points within a value range to parcel boundary

Tags: raster, arcmap, point, ndvi, floating

I have an NDVI with values of -0.99 to 0.88. The raster is floating points with no attribute table. I also have farms as parcel polygons.

Using ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro, how can I intersect only the floating pixel values of 0.08 to 0.20 that are on my specified parcels? I want to identify the farms that are changing crops, and last year that was the value range.

Comment: Use the `Extract by Mask` tool to get the raster data for the selected fields, and the `con` raster function to extract the values in the specified range.

Comment: Thank you! I will give this a try and let you know how it goes.